# PineScript "barssince" trouble

Tags: finance, pine-script

I'm here asking for help because i'm in trouble with 'barssince' function. This function actually returns the bars count since the condition between () was met. My problem is that my condition is always true, it always have one value assigned to it so 'barssince' is always returning me "0" as result because condition is met in the current bar [0].

What I'm trying to do is to get the maximum/minimum RSI value in the last 80 days with the functions rsimax = highest(rsi14, 80) and rsimin = lowest(rsi14, 80) and after that i want to know how many bars away am I from the highest RSI value in the last 80 days.

EG: Maximum RSI in the last 80 days was 75 and it ocourred 12 days ago. I want the 'barrsince' function to return 12.

As i already said, the function rsimax always carry a value with it, because there always will be a maximum RSI value and the 'barssince' condition will always be true at bar [0].

```
//RSI Score
float rsiscore1 = 0
int spotmax = 0
int spotmin = 0
rsiscore1 := 0
spotmax := 0
spotmin := 0

rsimax = highest(rsi14, 80)
rsimax5 = highest(rsi14, 5)
rsimin = lowest(rsi14, 80)
rsimin5 = lowest(rsi14, 5)
spotmax := barssince (rsimax)
spotmin := barssince (rsimin)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the function `barssince` must be a condition, so the correct code is

```
spotmax := barssince(rsimax==rsi14)
spotmin := barssince(rsimin==rsi14)
```

It may be necessary to adjust the result depending on whether the extreme bars should be included in the calculation or not.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
spotmax = barssince(change(rsimax))
spotmin = barssince(change(rsimmin))
```